# Return item from another table in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

I am struggling to get this one to work!! i know its simple...

I have a table full of jobs, and a table containing locations (in order that new locations can be added dynamically and populate dropdowns etc.

What I want to do it return all jobs at one location (not a problem) they are assigned a location ID that corresponds with an ID per location (which contains job_location_ID, job_Location_name, job_Location_Country)

```
sql = "SELECT  [job_ID],
        [job_ref],
        [job_title],
        [job_description],
        [job_location]
FROM    [Web_Xtr_HR]
WHERE   (
          ( [job_ext_int_both] = 1 )
          AND ( [job_location] = " + theIndex + " )
        )
ORDER BY [job_ID] DESC"
```

This reads all the items in, so what i need to do, per result is include the job_Location_name that is associated, with the job_Location_ID in the other table ([Web_Xtr_Job_Locations])

help!

Comment: This will be the first of about 20 comments to inform you that your code is prone to SQL injection attacks.  You should consider using command parameters: http://forums.asp.net/t/886691.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Inner Join like this:

```
"SELECT  [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations].job_Location_name,
        [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ID],
        [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ref],
        [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_title],
        [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_description],
        [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_location]
FROM    [Web_Xtr_HR]
        INNER JOIN [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations]
            ON [Web_Xtr_HR].job_location_id = [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations].job_location_id
WHERE   (
          ( [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ext_int_both] = 1 )
          AND ( [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_location] = " + theIndex + " )
        )
ORDER BY [job_ID] DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to *join* the two tables, to make it possible to select columns from both of them.

```
SELECT  job_ID,
        job_title,
        job_Location_Name
FROM    Web_Xtr_HR
        INNER JOIN Web_Xtr_Job_Locations
            ON Web_Xtr_Hr.job_Location_ID = Web_Xtr_Job_Locations.job_LocationID
WHERE   job_ext_int_both = 1 -- Add more filters as needed.
```

`INNER JOIN` will return elements where there is a match in both the tables. The field(s) to match on are determined by the `ON` line.

Comment: I've been trying that but I think I got myself in a mess!!
I'll have another stab following your syntax.

Comment: @DarkcatStudios I just saw a typo that I fixed - I had typed a `=` instead of a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT  [job_ID],
        [job_ref],
        [job_title],
        [job_description],
        [job_location]
FROM    [Web_Xtr_HR]
        INNER JOIN [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations]
            ON [Web_Xtr_HR].job.Location_ID = [Web_Xtr_HR]
WHERE   (
          ( [job_ext_int_both] = 1 )
          AND ( [job_location] = " + theIndex + " )
        )
ORDER BY [job_ID] DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, after a bit of mashing about i ended up with:

```
SELECT 
[Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ID], 
[Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ref], 
[Web_Xtr_HR].[job_title], 
[Web_Xtr_HR].[job_description], 
[Web_Xtr_HR].[job_location], 
[Web_Xtr_Job_Locations].[job_location_name], 
[Web_Xtr_Job_Locations].[job_location_country] 
FROM 
[Web_Xtr_HR]
    INNER JOIN [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations]
    ON [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_Location] = [Web_Xtr_Job_Locations].[job_Location_ID]
WHERE   
(([Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ext_int_both] = 1 )
AND
([Web_Xtr_HR].[job_location] = " + theIndex + "))

ORDER BY [Web_Xtr_HR].[job_ID] DESC
```